# Autosize height on multiline asp.net textbox "readonly" when data bound

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a databound asp.net textbox "readonly" that I want the height to autosize based on the text coming from a database.
I have tried several of the posts but can't get any of them to work correctly.

[Autosize Text Area (Multiline asp:TextBox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786405/autosize-text-area-multiline-asptextbox)
The line counting is not clean at all and when I try to use JQuery http://plugins.jquery.com/autogrow/ I get "Object doesn't support property or method 'autogrow'"

I have also tried http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/
but I still get the "Object doesn't support property or method 'autosize'"

I have also tried http://www.jscripts.info/jtextarea.php
but I still get the "Object doesn't support property or method 'jtextarea'"

The following code gets me very close but it adds one extra row.
http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/02/17/automatically-adjust-the-hieght-of-the-textbox-based-on-its.aspx

I almost feel that I am doing something wrong when trying to import the javascript files.
Here is how I tried to use the js files.

1. Download the *.js file into my web project / scripts folder.
2. Right click on the file in VS and set "Build Action = Content" and "Copy to Output Directory = Do not copy".
3. Open TestPage.aspx then add the following into the "head"..
4. Add script into the body like
   `<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $('textarea').autogrow();
           });
       </script>`
5. Add SOME LONG TEXT... into the body

Replace "autosize" with any of the javascript files and functions I have tried and I still get the same problem.

I need help... It can be in CSS, JavaScript, JQuery, .NET codebehind... I just need something that works.
And NO I can't just use a label. "textbox is a requirement".

Comment: If the solution you tried adds one more row then you can just remove it by adding -1 or remove the +1 from the else statement.

Comment: Well the problem was not with the javascript it was that Telerik RadScriptManager was causing external javascript files to not work. Anyway after trying all the javascript files listed above, AutoSize http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/ was the best and it is also in a NuGet...